# Extracing href's/urls from html with SED/AWK/GREP

Tags: html, parsing, sed, awk

I need to extract all the urls between the phrases 'Today's Racing' and 'Tomorrow's Racing' in the following html.

```
</noscript></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div><table id="pageRC3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td id="pageRC3cellLeft" valign="top"><div class="box" style="width:620px;"><table width="100%" cellspacing="6" class="ifTable"><thead><tr><td colspan="10">Today's Racing:</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury">Newbury</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury/13:40" title="1m 2f 6yrds Class 5 MC Seafoods Amateur Riders Handicap (Div 1) (3yo plus)">13:40</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury/14:10" title="1m 2f 6yrds Class 5 MC Seafoods Amateur Riders Handicap (Div 2) (3yo plus)">14:10</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury/14:40" title="6f 8yrds Class 4 Academy Insurance Irish E B F Maiden Stakes (Div 1) (2-yo)">14:40</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury/15:15" title="6f 8yrds Class 4 Academy Insurance Irish E B F Maiden Stakes (Div 2) (2-yo)">15:15</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury/15:50" title="7f Class 4 Grundon Recycle Nursery (Str) (2-yo)">15:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury/16:20" title="1m 4f 5yrds Class 1 British Stallion Studs E B F Chalice Stakes (Fillies Listed) (3yo plus)">16:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury/16:55" title="5f 34yrds Class 4 Bathwick Tyres Handicap (3yo plus)">16:55</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/newbury/17:25" title="1m 2f 6yrds Class 5 AJC Premier Fillies Handicap (3-yo)">17:25</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen">Market Rasen</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen/13:50" title="2m 1f Class 4 RAF Benevolent Fund &amp; RAF Waddington Airshow Handicap Hurdle (Div 1) (4yo plus)">13:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen/14:20" title="2m 1f Class 4 RAF Benevolent Fund &amp; RAF Waddington Airshow Handicap Hurdle (Div 2) (4yo plus)">14:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen/14:50" title="2m 1f Class 4 RAFBF Midshires Powerchairs Novices Hurdle (4yo plus)">14:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen/15:25" title="2m 5f Class 4 Richard The Big Show Stag Hutchinson Novices Hurdle (4yo plus)">15:25</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen/16:00" title="2m 3f Class 3 RAFBF Safeway Scaffold Ltd Handicap Hurdle (4yo plus)">16:00</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen/16:30" title="2m 4f Class 3 RAFBF Prolinx Ltd Handicap Chase (4yo plus)">16:30</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen/17:05" title="3m 1f Class 4 Oniz Tiptoes 100th Run Handicap Chase (4yo plus)">17:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/market-rasen/17:35" title="2m 1f Class 6 RAFBF Mood International Mares Intermediate Open NH Flat Race (4-6yo)">17:35</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork">Cork</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork/13:55" title="6f Irish Stallion Farms E B F Maiden (2-yo)">13:55</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork/14:25" title="6f Corkracecourse Ie Handicap (3-yo)">14:25</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork/14:55" title="5f Mallow Apprentice Handicap (50-75) (3yo plus)">14:55</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork/15:30" title="1m 0f Class 1 Platinum Stakes (Listed) (3yo plus)">15:30</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork/16:05" title="1m 4f Class 1 Irish Stallion Farms E B F Give Thanks Stakes (Fillies Group 3) (3yo plus)">16:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork/16:35" title="1m 4f Tote Trifecta Rollover Handicap (47-65) (Div 1) (4yo plus)">16:35</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork/17:10" title="1m 4f Tote Trifecta Rollover Handicap (47-65) (Div 2) (4yo plus)">17:10</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/cork/17:40" title="7f Family Day Out Maiden (3yo plus)">17:40</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/chester">Chester</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/chester/14:00" title="6f 18yrds Class 4 Liverpool One Nursery (2-yo)">14:00</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/chester/14:30" title="7f 2yrds Class 4 M&amp;S Bank E B F Maiden Stakes (2-yo)">14:30</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/chester/15:05" title="6f 18yrds Class 1 M&amp;S Bank Queensferry Stakes (Listed) (3yo plus)">15:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/chester/15:40" title="7f 122yrds Class 3 Halliwell Jones BMW Mile Handicap (3yo plus)">15:40</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/chester/16:10" title="6f 18yrds Class 2 British Stallion Studs Supporting British Racing E B F Conditions Stakes (2-yo)">16:10</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/chester/16:45" title="1m 4f 66yrds Class 4 New Fashioned Banking Handicap (3yo plus)">16:45</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/chester/17:15" title="1m 2f 75yrds Class 5 M&amp;S Bank Handicap (3-yo)">17:15</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway">Galway</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway/14:15" title="2m 2f Martinstown Opportunity Handicap Hurdle (81-116) (4yo plus)">14:15</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway/14:45" title="2m 0f Easyfix E B F Mares Handicap Hurdle (4yo plus)">14:45</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway/15:20" title="2m 1f Galway Bay FM Beginners Chase (4yo plus)">15:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway/15:55" title="2m 1f Connacht Tribune Handicap Chase (4yo plus)">15:55</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway/16:25" title="7f Galway Shopping Centre Handicap (50-75) (3yo plus)">16:25</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway/17:00" title="1m 4f Trappers Inn Handicap (50-80) (3yo plus)">17:00</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway/17:30" title="1m 4f Sean Cleary Memorial E B F Fillies Maiden (3-4yo)">17:30</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/galway/18:00" title="2m 0f Fr Breen Memorial (Pro-Am) Flat Race (4-7yo)">18:00</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellspacing="6" width="100%" class="ifTable"><thead><tr><td colspan="10">Tomorrow's Racing:</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-ripon">Ripon</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-ripon/14:15" title="6f Class 5 Irish Stallion Farms E B F Maiden Stakes (2-yo)">14:15</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-ripon/14:45" title="5f Class 6 Follow At RiponRaces On Twitter Selling Handicap (3-yo)">14:45</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-ripon/15:15" title="1m 1f 170yrds Class 4 Children s Day Handicap (3yo plus)">15:15</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-ripon/15:45" title="6f Class 3 Armstrong Memorial Handicap (3yo plus)">15:45</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-ripon/16:15" title="5f Class 4 At The Races Sky 415 Handicap (3-yo)">16:15</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-ripon/16:45" title="1m 4f 10yrds Class 5 toteexacta Maiden Stakes (3yo plus)">16:45</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-ripon/17:15" title="1m 4f 10yrds Class 5 SIS Live Handicap (3yo plus)">17:15</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas">Naas</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas/14:20" title="7f Irish Stallion Farms E B F Maiden (2-yo)">14:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas/14:50" title="7f Book On-Line At Naasracecourse Com Handicap (47-65) (3-yo)">14:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas/15:20" title="6f Breda Miley Race (2-yo)">15:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas/15:50" title="6f Follow Naas On Facebook Handicap (47-65) (3yo plus)">15:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas/16:20" title="2m 3f Sallins Hurdle (4yo plus)">16:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas/16:50" title="2m 0f Www Naasracecourse Com Handicap Hurdle (80-109) (4yo Plus)">16:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas/17:20" title="1m 0f Naas Apprentice Handicap (50-85) (3yo plus)">17:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-naas/17:50" title="1m 0f Irish Stallion Farms E B F Fillies Maiden (3yo plus)">17:50</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-kempton">Kempton</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-kempton/14:30" title="1m 3f Class 6 Ladies Day At Kempton 08 09 2012 Apprentice Handicap (3-yo)">14:30</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-kempton/15:00" title="1m 0f Class 6 Betfair Claiming Stakes (3-yo)">15:00</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-kempton/15:30" title="1m 0f Class 5 Jimmy Miller Lifetime In Racing Handicap (London Mile Qualifier) (3yo plus)">15:30</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-kempton/16:00" title="6f Class 5 Betfair Supporting Grassroots Racing Median Auction Maiden Stakes (2-yo)">16:00</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-kempton/16:30" title="7f Class 5 Betfair Com Median Auction Maiden Stakes (3-4yo)">16:30</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-kempton/17:00" title="1m 4f Class 5 Olly Murs 17 08 2012 Fillies Handicap (3yo plus)">17:00</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-kempton/17:30" title="7f Class 4 Betfair Don t Settle For Less Handicap (3-yo)">17:30</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-cork">Cork</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-cork/14:35" title="2m 0f Family Day Out Maiden Hurdle (4yo plus)">14:35</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-cork/15:05" title="2m 0f Cork Handicap Hurdle (81-123) (4yo plus)">15:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-cork/15:35" title="3m 0f Www Mallow Ie Hurdle (4yo Plus)">15:35</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-cork/16:05" title="2m 2f Follow Us On Twitter Handicap Hurdle (80-95) (4yo plus)">16:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-cork/16:35" title="2m 3f Corkracecourse Ie Maiden Hurdle (4yo Plus)">16:35</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-cork/17:05" title="2m 3f Martinstown Opportunity Handicap Hurdle (80-109) (4yo plus)">17:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-cork/17:35" title="2m 3f Follow Us On Facebook Flat Race (5-7yo)">17:35</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-carlisle">Carlisle</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-carlisle/18:05" title="1m 1f 61yrds Class 6 Carlisle-races Co Uk Claiming Stakes (Pro-Am Lady Riders Race) (3yo Plus)">18:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-carlisle/18:35" title="5f 193yrds Class 6 Integral UK Handicap (Pro-Am Lady Riders Race) (4yo plus)">18:35</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-carlisle/19:05" title="5f 193yrds Class 5 Beadle &amp; Hill Handicap (Pro-Am Lady Riders Race) (4yo plus)">19:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-carlisle/19:35" title="2m 1f 52yrds Class 6 Lloyd Mini Handicap (Pro-Am Lady Riders Race) (4yo plus)">19:35</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-carlisle/20:05" title="7f 200yrds Class 4 Edinburgh Woollen Mill Stakes (Professional Lady Riders Handicap) (3yo plus)">20:05</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-carlisle/20:35" title="1m 3f 107yrds Class 6 Live Music After Racing Tonight Handicap (Pro-Am Lady Riders Race) (4yo plus)">20:35</a></td></tr><tr><td class="ifFirstCol"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-wolverhampton">Wolverhampton</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-wolverhampton/18:20" title="1m 4f 50yrds Class 5 Follow Us On Twitter At WolvesRaces Amateur Riders Handicap (3yo plus)">18:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-wolverhampton/18:50" title="5f 20yrds Class 6 Betfred Mobile Sports Handicap (3yo plus)">18:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-wolverhampton/19:20" title="5f 216yrds Class 5 Holiday Inn Wolverhampton Maiden Fillies Stakes (2-yo)">19:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-wolverhampton/19:50" title="5f 216yrds Class 5 Betfred Mobile Lotto Handicap (3yo plus)">19:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-wolverhampton/20:20" title="1m 1f 103yrds Class 6 Download Our iPhone App Median Auction Maiden Stakes (3-4yo)">20:20</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-wolverhampton/20:50" title="1m 0f 141yrds Class 4 Betfred Mobile Casino Handicap (3yo plus)">20:50</a></td><td><a href="/horse-racing-betting/2012-08-06-wolverhampton/21:20" title="1m 0f 141yrds Class 6 Betfred The Bonus King Handicap (3yo plus)">21:20</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellspacing="6" width="100%" class="ifTable"><thead><tr><td colspan="10">Ante-Post Racing:</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td valign="top"><table class="ifTableAp"><tr><td class="ifTitle"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat">Flat</a><br /><select onChange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != '') { document.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; }"><option value="">Select market...</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/blue-sq-cavalry-charge">Blue SQ Cavalry Charge</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/sprint-cup">Sprint Cup</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/juddmonte-international-stakes">Juddmonte International Stakes</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/nunthorpe-stakes">Nunthorpe Stakes</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/betfred-ebor">Betfred Ebor</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/st-leger">St Leger</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/golden-rose">Golden Rose</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/prix-de-l-arc-de-triomphe">Prix De L Arc De Triomphe</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/champion-stakes">Champion Stakes</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/cox-plate">Cox Plate</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/melbourne-cup">Melbourne Cup</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/2000-guineas">2000 Guineas</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/1000-guineas">1000 Guineas</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/the-derby">The Derby</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/flat/ascot-gold-cup">Ascot Gold Cup</option></select></td></tr></table></td><td valign="top"><table class="ifTableAp"><tr><td class="ifTitle"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/national-hunt">National Hunt</a><br /><select onChange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != '') { document.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; }"><option value="">Select market...</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/national-hunt/king-george-vi-chase">King George VI Chase</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/national-hunt/grand-national">Grand National</option></select></td></tr></table></td><td valign="top"><table class="ifTableAp"><tr><td class="ifTitle"><a href="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival">Cheltenham Festival</a><br /><select onChange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != '') { document.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; }"><option value="">Select market...</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/supreme-novices-hurdle">Supreme Novices Hurdle</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/arkle-trophy">Arkle Trophy</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/champion-hurdle">Champion Hurdle</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/david-nicholson-mares-hurdle">David Nicholson Mares Hurdle</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/rsa-chase">RSA Chase</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/queen-mother-champion-chase">Queen Mother Champion Chase</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/ryanair-chase">Ryanair Chase</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/world-hurdle">World Hurdle</option><option value="/horse-racing-betting/ante-post-racing/cheltenham-festival/cheltenham-gold-cup">Cheltenham Gold Cup</option></select></td></tr></table></td></tr></tbody></table><hr /><table width="100%" cellspacing="10" class="ifTable"><tr><td><a onclick="showHideById('sportinglifeTipsContainer');showHideById('slArrowUp');showHideById('slArrowDown');" style="color: #E74900;" href="javascript:void(0);">Sporting Life Tips <img id="slArrowDown" alt="Expand daily preview section" src="http://static.oddschecker.com/i/icons/racing-arrow-down.gif" style="vertical-align: middle;" /><img id="slArrowUp" alt="Hide daily preview section" src="http://static.oddschecker.com/i/icons/racing-arrow-up.gif" style="vertical-align: middle; display: none;" /></a> |
```

I tried using SED, but since the start and end strings are on the same linke, I don't think using SED is appropriate.

```
sed -e '1,/Today/d' -e '/Tomorrow/,$d' > "file.txt"
```

I've been trying grep as follows, with little success:

```
grep -o -E "href="([^"#]+)"" index.html >> url-list.txt
```

I've also been trying AWK as follows:

```
awk /Today/,/Tomorrow/ > awk -F "$FSEP" "{ print $3 }"
```

Are these the right tools to try? Any suggestions about how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use an XML parser?  Perl is probably available on a system that has sed and awk and it has libraries for parsing xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with only sed, grep, and cut utilities:

```
sed -e 's/</\n/g' index.html |\
sed -n "/Today's Racing/,/Tomorrow's Racing/p" |\
grep href |\
cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr '<' '\n' < index.html | csplit -n 2 -s - "%Today's Racing%"
csplit -n 2 -s -f /tmp/t2 /tmp/t100 "/Tomorrow's Racing/"
grep href /tmp/t200 | cut -f 2 -d '"' > url-list.txt
rm /tmp/t100 /tmp/t200 /tmp/t201
```

Note: This is *extremely* non general. It doesn't handle comments, only single line hrefs, only hrefs in double quotes, and various other restrictions, for example it will find all `href`s not just those that are part of an `a` tag.

But it may work just fine for what you are doing.

There are other tools that can do it in one shot, but this works.

Comment: `sed` `grep` and `awk` are also unix (well, posix really) tools. Get `tr` `csplit` and `cut` from the same place you got those. `rm` is just delete, so use `del`, and change the file paths to not use `/tmp` since windows doesn't have that.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s:.*Today's Racing\(.*\)Tomorrow's Racing:\1:; s:a href[^\"]*.\([^\"]*\):\n=\:\1\n:g ; s:\n[^=][^\n]*::g ; :r s:^[^=][^\n]*:: ; s:^\n::; tr " FILE
```

You can also save this script into a file links.sed

```
s:.*Today's Racing\(.*\)Tomorrow's Racing:\1:
s:a href[^\"]*.\([^\"]*\):\n=\:\1\n:g
s:\n[^=][^\n]*::g
:r
s:^[^=][^\n]*::
s:^\n::
tr
```

and run it

```
sed -i -f links.sed FILE
```

Comment: yes, you can pipe it . You do so:

     wget xxx | >OUT_FILE sed -f links.sed